# HTML5 appcache with Chrome and the HTTPS Everywhere plugin causing cross site css not to load

Tags: html, google-chrome, https, manifest, html5-appcache

I have run into an issue with one of my webpages that was changed to use the HTML5 appcache feature. Chrome 19 (ad I assume earlier versions) is blocking my cross site css files when the appcache is enabled on a page. The page, http://www.ericperrets.info/index.html, loads a number of image/css files from my server and a number of css files from a google url/servers. Below is the epi.appcache file content

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#

CACHE:
/default.css
/800px.css
/images/bg.jpg
/images/spwright.png
/images/spwright2.png
/images/meme.jpg
/favicon.ico
/Resume%20-%20Eric%20Perret.pdf

NETWORK:
/index.html
*
http://*
https://*
```

This works find when the page is loaded in the latest safari or firefox, but when I try to load it in Chrome, it blocks the calls to http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie|Candal&v1&text=ERIC%20PT%E2%80%99SINFOAesumWorkaplntcfLidh%2C

[image: Screenshot of the waterfall chart and console with the error]

**Update:** I fixed the issue by disabling one of my plug-ins that I had for Chrome: [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere).  This is a really useful plugin.  Is there a way around this issue other than changing the URL to https?

Comment: Created a bug against https-everywhere: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/5585